# violation of primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

i can only edit ONE data but when i edit TWO data they give me this error. My Primary Key is part_no. i also try to counter my part_no using

> (this is just a shortcut just to highlight the error)

```
var counter=1;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {

                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", counter);
counter ++;
}
}
```

this code also give me an error of violation

> (my full code)

```
string date = dt_date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["POSdb"].ConnectionString);

            sc.Open();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {

                    string strQry = "UPDATE CounterChecking "+
                    "SET part_no = @c0,po_no = @po_no,invoice = @invoice,part_name = @c1,"+
                    "date = @date,color = @c2,qty_ordered = @c3,qty_for_delivery = @c4,qty_recieved = @c5,"+
                    "variance = @c6,unit_price = @c7, total = @c8, remarks = @c9 "+
                    "WHERE po_no= '" + cb_po_search.Text + "'";
                    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(strQry, sc);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c0", row.Cells[0].Value);

                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@po_no", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_ponumber2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tb_invoice2.Text;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c1", row.Cells[1].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = date;
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c2", row.Cells[2].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c3", row.Cells[3].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c4", row.Cells[4].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c5", row.Cells[5].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c6", row.Cells[6].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c7", row.Cells[7].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c8", row.Cells[8].Value);
                    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c9", row.Cells[9].Value);
                    scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sc.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated!");}
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to update the primary key... that's why you are getting the violation.

Comment: when you do update or insert then refresh the gridview also for new values to update if you want to get the value for part_no on base of values in grid view

Comment: i'm just only updating the values not the primary key do i need to remove it?

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican updating PK in MS SQL Server is allowed and it just when for example new value for update is conflicted with anotherone then gives error

Comment: @Farhang Amary what is the best find ways to code my sql query?. because it defends on my client if he gonna edit the part_no

Comment: you have to review it in these cases: 1.is there a trigger on the table which may prevent it? 2.is the new value for update for part_no is the same as another value for part_no in the table? 3.it's FK 4.is there another constraint on the table

Comment: @FarhangAmary my code is running now. i can edit multiple. but the problem is i can't edit the primary key. it's 50-50 for me if my client is gonna edit the primary key

Comment: I prefer to fix it all, but almost nobody does not allow users to update PK you can don't show it to user if it's not required for her/him

Comment: can i have a po_id as a primary key then part_name is just a values?

Comment: yes it's good idea, however it's your scenario and you know all the business logic and situation of project that's why I can't say anything 100% surely.

Comment: okay okay thank you for the understanding of the values of PRIMARY KEYS now i understand. can u vote my question? this will help the others

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer is that your WHERE clause is returning multiple rows.

Additionally, it seems odd that you are assigning the part_no as part of the update. Are you intending to change your primary key? Depending on what that column is, it's quite possible that you're assigning the same PK multiple times. What is in that column?

PS - this code is open to SQL injection attacks (cb_po_search)

Comment: yes i have a search button. column[0] is the part_no

Comment: I would recommend starting up a profiler (SQL Profiler, or a DMV that shows executed SQL). See the actual SQL will shed light on this.